# Deserialize Json when variable quantity of entry

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

So I have a Json file looking like this

```
{
"Item":[
 "name": {
   "type": "value",
   "type2": "value",
   "0":{
     "InnerType1":"innerValue",
     "InnerType2":"innerValue",
     "InnerType3":"innerValue",
   },
   "1":{
     "InnerType1":"innerValue",
     "InnerType2":"innerValue",
     "InnerType3":"innerValue",
   }
 },"name2": {
   "type": "value",
   "type2": "value",
   "0":{
     "InnerType1":"innerValue",
     "InnerType2":"innerValue",
     "InnerType3":"innerValue",
   }
 },"name3": {
   "type": "value",
   "type2": "value",
   "0":{
     "InnerType1":"innerValue",
     "InnerType2":"innerValue",
     "InnerType3":"innerValue",
   },
   "1":{
     "InnerType1":"innerValue",
     "InnerType2":"innerValue",
     "InnerType3":"innerValue",
   },
   "2":{
     "InnerType1":"innerValue",
     "InnerType2":"innerValue",
     "InnerType3":"innerValue",
   }
 },
]
}
```

My problem is with the "0","1" and "2" cause they are not always present in my data, and maybe one time i'll have 42 entries of this type. The "0","1" and "2" get exactly the same inner type but not the same value.

So anyone have an idea, cause only one I have is a manual deserialise with an for to iterate 0 to x and stop when i dont have the number, but its not a good idea.

Thank you and have a good day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use this, you no need to worry about the Json keys

```
 IDictionary<string, JToken> jsondata = JObject.Parse(json);

 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> innerData in jsondata) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}=> {1}",innerData.Key, innerData.Value.ToString()); 
 }
```

JToken is the base class of JObject , JArray , JProperty , so these types can easily handled by JToken